# Finding coordinates points in circle sector matlab

Tags: matlab

I distribute 200 points randomly

```
r2 = rc*sqrt(rand(200,1));
theta2 = (pi/2)*rand(200,1);
x= r2.*cos(theta2);
y= r2.*sin(theta2);
```

This circle will be subdivided into some sectors I would like to know the coordinates of theses points
How can i determine the location of each point and in each sector it will be located??
The sectors are defined as follow:

```
for i=1:N % N:Number of sector  
r= (rc/N)*i;   
ang=0:0.01:2*pi;
p=rcos(ang); 
%region(i)=i; 
plot(xp,yp);
```

Comment: You've already got the locations of each point though...?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which points fall in a sector? That's probably just some pretty simple indexing, but we'd need to know how you are defining your sectors.

Comment: I want to know which points fall in a sector; for example the point (2.505, 0.9144) belongs the second sector. My sectors are defined as follow:                                                                                                       for i=1:N % N:Number of sector
r= (rc/N)*i;
ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
xp=r*cos(ang);
yp=r*sin(ang);
%region(i)=i;
plot(xp,yp);
hold on
end

Comment: Please ***edit your question*** to include that code defining the sector. It is too difficult to read as a comment

Comment: Please @Dan How can i do this indexing

Comment: But are you basically asking which points fall within a defined range of `theta2` values? So like `points = theta2 >= rtheta_min && theta2 <= theta_max`, and now if you want the x/y coords you just do `x(points)` and `y(points)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circular sector of radius *r*<sub>0</sub> with the center in the origin of the coordinates is the set of points with the coordinates (*r*, *θ*) such as:

- *r* < *r*<sub>0</sub>
- *θ*<sub>1</sub> < *θ* < *θ*<sub>2</sub>

So, if `r0` is your radius limit (scalar), and `th1` and `th2` are the angle limits (scalars), then the following code should give you the points that are falling into the sector:

```
select = (r2 < r0) & (th1 < theta2) & (theta2 < th2);
xs = x(select);
ys = y(select);
```

To test the result:

```
figure();
plot(x,y,'ob', xs,ys,'or');
```

**Note:** Please note that you have to define the limits `r0`, `th1` and `th2`.

Comment: @Dan I think that `&` is the correct operator: I.m looking for the logical index of the elements that satisfy all the conditions. `&&` is restricted to logical scalar evaluation ("lazy", or short-circuit logical operators); for details check http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html

Comment: Thank you very much it is worked now with your solution @CST-Link,